Variable subdivision creating artifacts
I'm currently implementing a method for subdividing an icosahedron found here that isn't quite working as expected due to the artifacts created (and the way the triangles are oriented)

The problem with the current generation is the lines inside the sphere branching out randomly (there are also some triangles that are missing but that's hard to see with the wireframe), which was not what I was expecting
This is the code I used to port over the implementation
#define MAX_ENTRY_COUNT 2048U

typedef struct
{
    vec3s pos;
    float temperature;
    float time;
}   vk_vertex;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t v1, v2, v3;
}   vk_triangle;

typedef struct
{
    vk_triangle faces[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT];
    uint32_t face_count;
}   faces;

typedef struct
{
    vk_vertex verts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT];
    float temperature;
    float time;
    uint32_t vert_count;
}   verts;

typedef struct
{
    verts verts;
    faces faces;
    float radius;
}   icosahedron;

typedef struct
{
    verts verts;
    size_t vertex_size;
    faces faces;
    size_t face_size;
    float radius;
}   sphere;

static uint32_t sphere_verts_add(sphere *s, vec3s vert)
{
    float len = sqrtf((vert.x * vert.x) + (vert.y * vert.y) + (vert.z * vert.z));

    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].pos = (vec3s) {{((vert.x / len) * s->radius), ((vert.y / len) * s->radius), ((vert.z / len) * s->radius)}};
    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].temperature = s->verts.temperature;
    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].time = s->verts.time;

    return s->verts.vert_count++;
}

static uint32_t sphere_faces_add(sphere *s, vk_triangle face)
{
    s->faces.faces[s->faces.face_count] = face;

    return s->faces.face_count++;
}

static uint32_t icosahedron_verts_add(icosahedron *ico, vec3s vert)
{
    float len = sqrtf((vert.x * vert.x) + (vert.y * vert.y) + (vert.z * vert.z));

    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].pos = (vec3s) {{((vert.x / len) * ico->radius), ((vert.y / len) * ico->radius), ((vert.z / len) * ico->radius)}};
    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].temperature = ico->verts.temperature;
    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].time = ico->verts.time;

    return ico->verts.vert_count++;
}

static uint32_t icosahedron_faces_add(icosahedron *ico, vk_triangle face)
{
    ico->faces.faces[ico->faces.face_count] = face;

    return ico->faces.face_count++;
}
static void icosahedron_verts_init(icosahedron *ico)
{
    float phi = ((1.0f + sqrtf(5.0f)) / 2.0f);

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ phi,  0.0f,  1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ phi,  0.0f, -1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 1.0f,  phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f,  1.0f,  phi}});

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f, -1.0f,  phi}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 1.0f, -phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f, -1.0f, -phi}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f,  1.0f, -phi}});

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-1.0f,  phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-phi,  0.0f,  1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-1.0f, -phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-phi,  0.0f, -1.0f}});

    float angle = atanf(ico->verts.verts[0].pos.x / ico->verts.verts[0].pos.z);
    float ca = cosf(angle);
    float sa = sinf(angle);

    mat4s rot = GLMS_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT;
    rot.m00 = ca;
    rot.m02 = -sa;
    rot.m20 = sa;
    rot.m22 = ca;

    for(uint32_t i = 0U; i < ico->verts.vert_count; i++)
    {
        ico->verts.verts[i].pos = glms_vec3_rotate_m4(rot, ico->verts.verts[i].pos);
    }
}

static void icosahedron_faces_init(icosahedron *ico)
{
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 1U,  2U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  3U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 3U,  4U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 4U,  5U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 5U,  1U,  0U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U,  7U,  1U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  1U,  7U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 7U,  8U,  2U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  8U,  3U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 8U,  9U,  3U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 3U,  9U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 9U, 10U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U,  5U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U,  6U,  5U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U,  1U,  5U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U, 11U,  7U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 7U, 11U,  8U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 8U, 11U,  9U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 9U, 11U, 10U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U, 11U,  6U});
}

static icosahedron icosahedron_init(float radius, float temperature, float time)
{
    icosahedron ico = {0U};
    ico.radius = radius;
    ico.verts.temperature = temperature;
    ico.verts.time = time;

    icosahedron_verts_init(&ico);
    icosahedron_faces_init(&ico);

    return ico;
}

static verts icosahedron_verts_refine(uint32_t granularity)
{
    verts new =
    {
        .vert_count = 0U
    };

    float values[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0.0f};
    uint32_t offsets[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};
    uint32_t starts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};
    uint32_t stops[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
    {
        values[i] = (float) i / (float) (granularity - 1U);
        offsets[i] = (granularity - i);

        if (i > 0U)
        {
            starts[i] = starts[i - 1U] + offsets[i - 1U];
        }

        stops[i] = starts[i] + offsets[i];
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < offsets[i]; j++)
        {
            new.vert_count = starts[i] + j;
            new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.x = values[offsets[i] - 1U - j];
            new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.y = values[j];
            new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.z = values[i];
        }
    }

    return new;
}

static faces icosahedron_faces_refine(uint32_t granularity)
{
    faces new =
    {
        .faces = {0U},
        .face_count = 0U
    };

    uint32_t n = granularity + 2U;
    uint32_t shift = 0U;

    for (uint32_t row = 0U; row < (n - 1U); row++)
    {
        new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + 1U;
        new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row;
        new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift;

        new.face_count++;

        for (uint32_t col = 1U; col < (n - 1U - row); col++)
        {
            new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift + n - row + col - 1U;

            new.face_count++;

            new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + col + 1U;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift + col;

            new.face_count++;
        }

        shift += n - row;
    }

    return new;
}

static void sphere_refine(sphere *s, uint32_t granularity, float temperature, float time)
{
    icosahedron ico = icosahedron_init(s->radius, temperature, time);

    vec3s temp_verts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {GLMS_VEC3_ZERO_INIT};
    uint32_t temp_inds[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};

    uint32_t index = 0U;

    verts refined_verts = icosahedron_verts_refine(granularity + 2U);
    faces refined_faces = icosahedron_faces_refine(granularity);

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < ico.faces.face_count; i++)
    {
        vk_triangle face = ico.faces.faces[i];
        vec3s p1 = ico.verts.verts[face.v1].pos;
        vec3s p2 = ico.verts.verts[face.v2].pos;
        vec3s p3 = ico.verts.verts[face.v3].pos;

        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < refined_verts.vert_count; j++)
        {
            temp_verts[j].x = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.x) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.x) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.x);
            temp_verts[j].y = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.y) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.y) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.y);
            temp_verts[j].z = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.z) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.z) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.z);

            sphere_verts_add(s, temp_verts[j]);
            temp_inds[j] = index;
            index++;
        }

        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < refined_faces.face_count; j++)
        {
            sphere_faces_add(s, (vk_triangle) {temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v1], temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v2], temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v3]});
        }
    }
}

sphere sphere_init(uint32_t granularity, float radius, float temperature, float time)
{
    sphere s = {0U};

    s.verts.temperature = temperature;
    s.verts.time = time;
    s.radius = radius;

    sphere_refine(&s, granularity, temperature, time);

    s.vertex_size = sizeof(s.verts.verts) / sizeof(s.verts.verts[0U]) * sizeof(vk_vertex);
    s.face_size = sizeof(s.faces.faces) / sizeof(s.faces.faces[0U]) * sizeof(vk_triangle);

    return s;
}

vec3s is a 3D vector type wrapped inside a struct coming from this library

I suggest you link to a video of the wireframe being rotated, or else it is not clear to viewers what the problem with your geometry is. Or an inline animated GIF that makes the problem clear.

@Engineer I cant add a gif sorry i did describe what the problem is (lines being randomly drawn out from within along with some triangles not rendering (not visible from picture))

Suit yourself. It is easy enough to post on youtube and link it here. But since you don't want to, the question probably won't get much attention, like the majority of questions posted here. Good luck.

I assumed this is in C (since the library you linked is also in C) & tagged accordingly; if that's not correct please edit the tags to reflect the language you are attempting to port into.

@Pikalek Correct

It appears that the subdivision code is preferring one vertex on the equator just right of center. It could be a hard-coded value, a pointer error, or inconsistent vertex type or ordering.

@agone Yeah that is whats happening i think it might be an ordering issue originating from the sphere_refine function

I cannot vote to close, for a typo....

This was embarrassing, but... as it turns out all I needed to do was change
for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
{
    for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < offsets[i]; j++)
    {
        new.vert_count = starts[i] + j;
        new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.x = values[offsets[i] - 1U - j];
        new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.y = values[j];
        new.verts[new.vert_count].pos.z = values[i];
    }
}

in the icosahedron_verts_refine function to
for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
{
    for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < offsets[i]; j++)
    {
        uint32_t index = starts[i] + j;
        new.verts[index].pos.x = values[offsets[i] - 1U - j];
        new.verts[index].pos.y = values[j];
        new.verts[index].pos.z = values[i];
    }
}

it's always the most idiotic things that go wrong. Anyways this is the final working code for anyone who cares
#define MAX_ENTRY_COUNT 2048U

typedef struct
{
    vec3s pos;
    float temperature;
    float time;
}   vk_vertex;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t v1, v2, v3;
}   vk_triangle;

typedef struct
{
    vk_triangle faces[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT];
    uint32_t face_count;
}   faces;

typedef struct
{
    vk_vertex verts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT];
    float temperature;
    float time;
    uint32_t vert_count;
}   verts;

typedef struct
{
    verts verts;
    faces faces;
    float radius;
}   icosahedron;

typedef struct
{
    verts verts;
    size_t vertex_size;
    faces faces;
    size_t face_size;
    float radius;
}   sphere;

static uint32_t sphere_verts_add(sphere *s, vec3s vert)
{
    float len = sqrtf((vert.x * vert.x) + (vert.y * vert.y) + (vert.z * vert.z));

    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].pos = (vec3s) {{((vert.x / len) * s->radius), ((vert.y / len) * s->radius), ((vert.z / len) * s->radius)}};
    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].temperature = s->verts.temperature;
    s->verts.verts[s->verts.vert_count].time = s->verts.time;

    return s->verts.vert_count++;
}

static uint32_t sphere_faces_add(sphere *s, vk_triangle face)
{
    s->faces.faces[s->faces.face_count] = face;

    return s->faces.face_count++;
}

static uint32_t icosahedron_verts_add(icosahedron *ico, vec3s vert)
{
    float len = sqrtf((vert.x * vert.x) + (vert.y * vert.y) + (vert.z * vert.z));

    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].pos = (vec3s) {{((vert.x / len) * ico->radius), ((vert.y / len) * ico->radius), ((vert.z / len) * ico->radius)}};
    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].temperature = ico->verts.temperature;
    ico->verts.verts[ico->verts.vert_count].time = ico->verts.time;

    return ico->verts.vert_count++;
}

static uint32_t icosahedron_faces_add(icosahedron *ico, vk_triangle face)
{
    ico->faces.faces[ico->faces.face_count] = face;

    return ico->faces.face_count++;
}
static void icosahedron_verts_init(icosahedron *ico)
{
    float phi = ((1.0f + sqrtf(5.0f)) / 2.0f);

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ phi,  0.0f,  1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ phi,  0.0f, -1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 1.0f,  phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f,  1.0f,  phi}});

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f, -1.0f,  phi}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 1.0f, -phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f, -1.0f, -phi}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{ 0.0f,  1.0f, -phi}});

    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-1.0f,  phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-phi,  0.0f,  1.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-1.0f, -phi,  0.0f}});
    icosahedron_verts_add(ico, (vec3s) {{-phi,  0.0f, -1.0f}});

    float angle = atanf(ico->verts.verts[0].pos.x / ico->verts.verts[0].pos.z);
    float ca = cosf(angle);
    float sa = sinf(angle);

    mat4s rot = GLMS_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT;
    rot.m00 = ca;
    rot.m02 = -sa;
    rot.m20 = sa;
    rot.m22 = ca;

    for(uint32_t i = 0U; i < ico->verts.vert_count; i++)
    {
        ico->verts.verts[i].pos = glms_vec3_rotate_m4(rot, ico->verts.verts[i].pos);
    }
}

static void icosahedron_faces_init(icosahedron *ico)
{
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 1U,  2U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  3U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 3U,  4U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 4U,  5U,  0U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 5U,  1U,  0U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U,  7U,  1U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  1U,  7U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 7U,  8U,  2U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 2U,  8U,  3U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 8U,  9U,  3U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 3U,  9U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 9U, 10U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U,  5U,  4U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U,  6U,  5U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U,  1U,  5U});

    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 6U, 11U,  7U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 7U, 11U,  8U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 8U, 11U,  9U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) { 9U, 11U, 10U});
    icosahedron_faces_add(ico, (vk_triangle) {10U, 11U,  6U});
}

static icosahedron icosahedron_init(float radius, float temperature, float time)
{
    icosahedron ico = {0U};
    ico.radius = radius;
    ico.verts.temperature = temperature;
    ico.verts.time = time;

    icosahedron_verts_init(&ico);
    icosahedron_faces_init(&ico);

    return ico;
}

static verts icosahedron_verts_refine(uint32_t granularity)
{
    verts new =
    {
        .vert_count = granularity * (granularity + 1U) / 2U
    };

    float values[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0.0f};
    uint32_t offsets[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};
    uint32_t starts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};
    uint32_t stops[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
    {
        values[i] = (float) i / (float) (granularity - 1U);
        offsets[i] = (granularity - i);

        if (i > 0U)
        {
            starts[i] = starts[i - 1U] + offsets[i - 1U];
        }

        stops[i] = starts[i] + offsets[i];
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < granularity; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < offsets[i]; j++)
        {
            uint32_t index = starts[i] + j;
            new.verts[index].pos.x = values[offsets[i] - 1U - j];
            new.verts[index].pos.y = values[j];
            new.verts[index].pos.z = values[i];
        }
    }

    return new;
}

static faces icosahedron_faces_refine(uint32_t granularity)
{
    faces new =
    {
        .faces = {0U},
        .face_count = 0U
    };

    uint32_t n = granularity + 2U;
    uint32_t shift = 0U;

    for (uint32_t row = 0U; row < (n - 1U); row++)
    {
        new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + 1U;
        new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row;
        new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift;

        new.face_count++;

        for (uint32_t col = 1U; col < (n - 1U - row); col++)
        {
            new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift + n - row + col - 1U;

            new.face_count++;

            new.faces[new.face_count].v1 = shift + col + 1U;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v2 = shift + n - row + col;
            new.faces[new.face_count].v3 = shift + col;

            new.face_count++;
        }

        shift += n - row;
    }

    return new;
}

static void sphere_refine(sphere *s, uint32_t granularity, float temperature, float time)
{
    icosahedron ico = icosahedron_init(s->radius, temperature, time);

    vec3s temp_verts[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {GLMS_VEC3_ZERO_INIT};
    uint32_t temp_inds[MAX_ENTRY_COUNT] = {0U};

    uint32_t index = 0U;

    verts refined_verts = icosahedron_verts_refine(granularity + 2U);
    faces refined_faces = icosahedron_faces_refine(granularity);

    for (uint32_t i = 0U; i < ico.faces.face_count; i++)
    {
        vk_triangle face = ico.faces.faces[i];
        vec3s p1 = ico.verts.verts[face.v1].pos;
        vec3s p2 = ico.verts.verts[face.v2].pos;
        vec3s p3 = ico.verts.verts[face.v3].pos;

        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < refined_verts.vert_count; j++)
        {
            temp_verts[j].x = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.x) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.x) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.x);
            temp_verts[j].y = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.y) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.y) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.y);
            temp_verts[j].z = (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.x * p1.z) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.y * p2.z) + (refined_verts.verts[j].pos.z * p3.z);

            sphere_verts_add(s, temp_verts[j]);
            temp_inds[j] = index;
            index++;
        }

        for (uint32_t j = 0U; j < refined_faces.face_count; j++)
        {
            sphere_faces_add(s, (vk_triangle) {temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v1], temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v2], temp_inds[refined_faces.faces[j].v3]});
        }
    }
}

sphere sphere_init(uint32_t granularity, float radius, float temperature, float time)
{
    sphere s = {0U};

    s.verts.temperature = temperature;
    s.verts.time = time;
    s.radius = radius;

    sphere_refine(&s, granularity, temperature, time);

    s.vertex_size = sizeof(s.verts.verts) / sizeof(s.verts.verts[0U]) * sizeof(vk_vertex);
    s.face_size = sizeof(s.faces.faces) / sizeof(s.faces.faces[0U]) * sizeof(vk_triangle);

    return s;
}

